# Tangent map of left-translation

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

In my lecture notes for Lie groups, it has the following line for calculating the tangent map for left-translation $L_g (x) = gx$ on an n-dimensional matrix lie group of $d \times d$ matrices.

$$(gx)_\mu ^\nu = g_\mu ^\tau x_\tau ^\nu \implies (T_xL_g)_{\mu \sigma}^{\nu \rho} = \frac{\partial (gx)_\mu^\nu}{\partial x_\rho^\sigma} = g_\mu^\tau \delta_\tau^\rho \delta_\sigma^\nu = g_\mu^\rho \delta_\sigma^\nu$$

My confusion is with the following equality: $$ (T_xL_g)_{\mu \sigma}^{\nu \rho} = \frac{\partial (gx)_\mu^\nu}{\partial x_\rho^\sigma} $$

Where does this come from?

Comment: What is your definition of $T_xL_g$?

Comment: He defines it as the tangent map from the tangent space at point $x \in M$ within the manifold, to the tangent space at point $gx \in M$ in the manifold, using the manifold map $L_g: M \rightarrow M, L_g(x) = gx$ which uses a specific $g \in M$

Comment: Yes, so what is the definition of the tangent map?

Comment: We define the tangent map $T_x F(v) (f) = v(f \circ F)$, where $v$ is defined in terms of differential operators. But my confusion is why the differential operator appears here when he is yet to sub in $v$ (he does that in the next line when he enforces left-invariance)

Comment: Unless he is just using the fact that the tangent map is linear so this is the way to get its matrix components?

Comment: "the tangent map is linear so this is the way to get its matrix components" - yep. The tangent map of some $F$, is represented in local coordinates by the Jacobian matrix of the local version of $F$.